# Softphone Layout Pop to Screen Flow - Input Variables

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, screen-flow, softphone

I am working on a screen pop feature for a softphone layout. I have created a screen flow to create a case, but I would like to be able to capture details from the inbound call-related matching contact record. However I am not sure how to capture and pass those variables from the Contact so I can assign them to the new created case record.

[image]

[image]

The calls are answered with NICE CXone Adapter, and I am not sure if there is a way to get the related single-matching record (contact) details. It seems like this could be accomplished in a flow without the need for dev work. Any advice would be helpful and greatly appreciate.

Online I find this article about screen popups, but it seems more geared towards Chat:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_multiple_screen_pop_actions.htm&type=5